# Copy all files with certain extension to another directory, while changing the extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cut

I want to copy all the files with extension `aaa` from directory `a` to directory `b`, replacing the extension to `bbb`. I tried to do something like this:

```
ls a | grep \.bla$ | cut --delimiter=. -f 1 | xargs cp a/{}.aaa b/{}.bbb
```

But it's really off. I want a oneliner, and not a bash script.

Comment: `rename .aaa .bbb *.aaa`?

Comment: Should the copying be done recursively?

Comment: not important. Not recursive will be enough

Comment: @user972014: and is the target directory empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you make the problem a bit too complicated, if the target directory is empty, you can do this with the following *one-liner*:

```
cp a/*.aaa b; rename 's/aaa$/bbb/' b/*.aaa
```

The script uses two commands with a `;` in between to execute the second after the first.

```
cp a/*.aaa b
```

copies all the files with the pattern `a/*.aaa` to the `b` directory. By doing this with a single call, the command will also be more efficient than using a pipe.

Next `rename` is a utility tool to perform a regex *find-and-replace* on the file names. By specifying `b/*.aaa` you will rename all files in `b` with the `*.aaa` regex. Now you only need to specify what to replace, this is done with the regex:

```
s/aaa$/bbb/
```

`aaa$` means the last three characters must be `aaa` and you replace them with `bbb` for each file.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks! Just out of curiosity - how could I accomplish it using my approach?

Comment: @user972014: I assume `\.bla` is `\.aaa`. A first problem is probably that the `cut` will `cut` the first part, so a file named `foo.bar.aaa` will be cut to `foo`. But in general I find `xarg` quite error prone, and currently I don't have a full linux shell available.

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm curious what sort of errors do you get with xargs ?

Comment: @JID: no errors, but working with `xarg` is in general harder, because it's one extra level of indirection. It's not `xarg` itself that is the problem, but human's skills of reasoning about indirection. I would avoid `xarg` as much as possible. Furthermore it's a bit less efficient since it spawns a process per item: while `cp` performs all copying at once, using element-wise `cp` will construct a new process each time.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's not the best option here, but i often use it over exec with find as i find it far more versatile and i've never really run into any trouble using it. Was just curious as to if there were any bugs or anything :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
cp -r a/ b/;for i in b/*; do mv {$i%.aaa}{.aaa,.bbb};done
```